# Triple For Loop in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, parallel.for

How can I write below C++ expression in CUDA? It's easy for first loop but after? ( I put my launch kernel )

launch kernel

```
dim3 dimBlock( 16 );
dim3 dimGrid( ( c + ( dimBlock.x - 1 ) ) / dimBlock.x );
```

C++ 3-loop expression

```
for ( int i = 0; i < c; i++ ) {

     int val1 = A[ i ];

     int val2 = B[ i ];

     for ( int j = val1 - 10; j < val1 + 10; j++ ) { 

         for ( int k = val2 -10; k < val2 + 10; k++ ) {

             //calculations
         }         
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 strategies that immediately come to mind.

1. Create one *thread* for each iteration of the outermost loop.  Then each thread will retain the inner 2 nested loops within it's thread code.

   ```
   __global__ void mykernel(int *A, int *B, int size_c, ...){
     int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
     if (i < size_c){
       int val1 = A[ i ];
       int val2 = B[ i ];
       for ( int j = val1 - 10; j < val1 + 10; j++ ) { 
         for ( int k = val2 -10; k < val2 + 10; k++ ) {
            //calculations
         }         
       }    
     }
   }

   %define nTPB 512
   dimBlock(nTPB);
   dimGrid((c+nTPB-1)/nTPB);
   ```
2. Create one *block* for each iteration of the outermost loop.  Then since the inner loops have iterations of 20 * 20 = 400 total iterations, assign one thread to each innermost loop iteration.

   ```
   __global__ void mykernel(int *A, int *B, ...){
     int i = blockIdx.x;
     int idx = threadIdx.x;
     int idy = threadIdx.y
     int val1 = A[ i ];
     int val2 = B[ i ];
     if (idx < 20) && (idy < 20) {
       int j = val1 - 10 + idy; 
       int k = val2 - 10 + idx;
          //calculations
     }            
   }

   dimBlock(20, 20);
   dimGrid(c);
   ```

Comment: thank you, i'm looking for second solution